# EF Core: How to access multi-layered encapsulated collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core) to encapsulate domain behavior private properties and readonly collections like this:

```
private readonly List<OrderItem> _orderItems; 
public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> OrderItems => _orderItems;
```

And you can get the order with encapsulated order items like this:

```
public async Task<Order> GetAsync(int orderId)
    {
        var order= await _context.Orders.FindAsync(orderId);
        if (order != null)
        {
            await _context.Entry(order)
                .Collection(i => i.OrderItems)
                .LoadAsync();
        }

        return order;
    }
```

But what if the order items itself have encapsulated lists like following tree:
Supplier -> Catalogs -> CatalogItems
How do I get the CatalogItems collection as well?

Comment: With the usual EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude`? There is nothing DDD specific.

Comment: Ok. I just wondered if there is a variation of the Collection() method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [explicit loading methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) `Collection` / `Reference` with [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) methods `Include` / `ThenInclude` through `Query` method as partially shown in the [Querying related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#querying-related-entities) section of the EF Core documentation.

For Supplier -> Catalogs -> CatalogItems example it could be like this:

```
public async Task<Supplier> GetAsync(int supplierId)
{
    var supplier = await _context.Suppliers.FindAsync(supplierId);
    if (supplier != null)
    {
        await _context.Entry(supplier)
            .Collection(e => e.Catalogs)
            .Query() // <--
            .Include(e => e.CatalogItems) // <--
            .LoadAsync();
    }
    return supplier;
}
```